# How to change the hamburger menu button and tab text's color in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been spending hours now to find that there's actually no way to change the tab texts and hamburger menu button's color in layout and styles xmls, can you help me how to change their color in my Home.java? (MainActivity)

Home.java

```
package com.example.jovie.canteen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.jovie.canteen.R.id.action_checkbox3;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    CoordinatorLayout homeLayout;

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        homeLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.CoordinatorLayout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Home.this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


            case R.id.action_notify:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
                return true;



            case R.id.action_checkbox1:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                homeLayout.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckbox);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_checkbox2:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                homeLayout.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckbox);
                return true;

            case action_checkbox3:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                homeLayout.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCheckbox);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
/**
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
*/
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;


        }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Breakfast");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Lunch");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Merienda");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.jovie.canteen/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.jovie.canteen/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/CoordinatorLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.jovie.canteen.Home"
    android:background="#B13D32">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/toolbar_popup_style"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            style="@style/toolbar_style"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24px" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my styles.xml if it's necessary:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/filter</item>
    </style>

    <style name="filter" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_filter_black_24px</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <!-- Set title color -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="toolbar_popup_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="toolbar_style" parent="">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">3dp</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/toolbar_popup_style</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/my_app_drawer</item>
</style>

<style name="my_app_drawer" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/custom_color</item>
</style>
```